# Ensure subclass is instance of generic type of superclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I am working on creating a java utils library and have come across a problem with generics. I have found a solution that lets the library work, but it seems like bad code practice and prone to undetected program failures. For question's sake, I've simplified the program into a minimum verifiable example.

Let's say I have an interface `Invokable<E>`, which is called upon to effect an `E`.

```
public interface Invokable<E> {

    void invoke(E e);

}
```

Let's say I have another interface, `InvokableFactory<E>`, which creates `Invokable<E>`s

```
public interface InvokableFactory<E> {

    Invokable<E> create();

}
```

Now let's say I have a class `InvokableUser<E>`, that is designed to be extended. It holds an `InvokableFactory<E>`, and uses it to create an `Invokable<E>`, which it then invokes with itself.

```
public class InvokableUser<E> {

    private InvokableFactory<E> factory;

    public InvokableUser(InvokableFactory<E> factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void start() {
        factory.create().invoke((E) this);
    }

}
```

You might see that my conundrum is that I'm trying to ensure that a subclass `InvokableUser`, extends `InvokableUser` of the generic type of itself. I'm trying to ensure that an `InvokableUser` contains a factory that produces `Invokable`s that can be invoked with the `InvokableUser` object, but still be passed an object of the type of the subclass of `InvokableUser` so that the `Invokable` can utilize methods added only by the subclass of `InvokableUser`.

I feel like I might not be explaining this very well, so for example, let's say there's a subclass of `Invokable` that needs to print out the `getString` method added by a subclass of `InvokableUser`, like this:

```
public class PrintingInvokable implements Invokable<PrintingInvokableUser> {

    @Override
    public void invoke(PrintingInvokableUser e) {
        System.out.println(e.getString());
    }

}

public class PrintingInvokableUser extends InvokableUser<PrintingInvokableUser> {

    public PrintingInvokableUser() {
        super(PrintingInvokable::new);
    }

    public String getString() {
        return "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)";
    }

}
```

If you create a `new PrintingInvokableUser()` and call `start()` on it, it will create a `new PrintingInvokable()` and call `invoke(this)` on it, when will then print out the `getString()` method of the `PrintingInvokableUser`.

While my code does work for this, it depends on the unwritten expectation that a subclass `Foo` of `InvokableUser` will extend `InvokableUser<Foo>`, involves an unchecked cast which is bad (and raises a compiler warning), seems to not even make use of the generic type as I could achieve the same effect with unparametrized types, and generally seems like there has to be a better way to do this.

If someone could point me in the right direction for how to do this, I'd be appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: It is impossible to avoid getting a warning on `(E) this`. It's a well known problem. There's an (unsatisfactory) solution called the "getThis trick", which you could google.

Comment: I'm guessing that's an abstract E method from which the subclass is expected to return `this`?

Comment: You guessed right. Personally I think it's a completely useless solution because you have to override it in every single class.

Comment: Yeah, it seems a choice between compiler-unenforced requirements and annoying code writing. I guess I'll just have to be very explicit in the javadocs about this requirement :p

Comment: @Phoenix: "I'm guessing that's an abstract E method from which the subclass is expected to return this" It's not required to return `this`. Well, it returns a value of type `E` (which may not even be the same type as the current class). You can implement your classes where `E` is the same type as the class, and you can return `this`. Someone else in the same situation can return some other instance of the class. Or someone else can have `E` that is not the same as the class, and they will then return an instance of that type. No matter what, it's type-safe.